# Show company users depending on login of their tenent admin in php yii

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-events

I have three tables as **roles**, **users** and **companies**. and their relationships as

for **Role.php**

```
public function relations()
    {       
       return array(
        'userRoles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRoles', 'id_roles'),
       );
    }
```

for **User.php**

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'userRoles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRole', 'id_users'),
            'companies' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'id_companies'),
        );
    }
```

For **Company.php**

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        'idCompnayType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CompanyType', 'id_company_type'),
        'companies' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Company', 'id_companies'),
        );
    }
```

I have following functionality-

In roles table there are two three roles as SuperAdmin(Adds Company and their TenantAdmin for that company), TenantAdmin(Adds users to company) and Users.

I have done to functionality for adding all users and assign them roles.

But **how can I display normal users as per their company when TenantAdmin for that company is logged in.**

Comment: Perhaps you could use [default scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#defaultScope-detail) to display data limited by tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option of `through` on your relation.

For Company model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'idCompnayType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CompanyType', 'id_company_type'),
        'companies' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Company', 'id_companies'),
        'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'id_companies'),
        'userRoles' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'UserRoles',array('id_users'=>'id_users'),'on'=>'userRoles.id_roles = 3','through'=>'users'),
    );
}
```

For UserRole model make sure you have a relationship like so:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'id_users'),
    );
}
```

A couple assumptions for this statement Primary Key in User is `id_users`, that the ID of the 'user' type is 3. This will give you an array of UserRole's that are the 'user' type. So you can easily list the users by using a foreach.

```
$user = User:model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
$company = Company::model()->findByPk($user->id_companies);
foreach($company->userRoles as $userRole) {
    $user = $userRole->user;
}
```